# Не могу понять почему не работает магический метод

Tags: python-3.x

Не могу понять почему не работает магический метод **mul**.

Должен выводить новый список умноженный на other. Выводит пустой список.

```
class SuperList(list):

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = []

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return list(map(lambda x: x * other, self.value))


a = SuperList()
a.append(87)
a.append(45)
a.append(54)

print(a)
print(a*10)
```

Comment: Вы нигде никак не заполняете `self.value`, вот он и остаётся пустой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это происходит потому что вызов метода `append` не меняет значение `self.value`.
Такой класс будет работать как вы и ожидаете:

```
class SuperList(list):

    def __init__(self):
        pass # self.value  нам не нужен
    
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return list(map(lambda x: x * other, self)) # self.value заменил на self
```